# Not able to install GWT plugin in eclipse

Tags: gwt, eclipse-plugin

I am using eclipse 3.7 version on windows xp platform.
I want to install GWT plugin for it so I tries below url for the installing plugin.
http://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/3.6

I checked three box in suggested list.
1. Google plugin for eclipse
2. Google App Engine Java SDK 1.7
3. Google Web Tool kit 2.4

I also checked the contact all update sites during installation problem.
But it is not installing the GWT plugin and giving me below error.

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=SDKProfile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle,2.4.0.v201208080120-rel-r37.
MD5 hash is not as expected. Expected: 4377ba085a0089b1641d9c989f4bd0cc and found 4cacae71d159d6c14fe5b09f04b2ec16.
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle,1.7.0.
MD5 hash is not as expected. Expected: 1ba46f6b6c57b36904abecef6ae99cba and found f142767a855d57c150e2383afd1c342e.
```

I am not getting the where the problem is.I also tried eclipse 3.6 but the same problem is also occurring in that version.
Please help me out.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Download your eclipse from here: http://www.springsource.org/downloads/sts-ggts. After installing, go to extension tab of Dashboard to choose google plugin to install. STS gives you a clean eclipse build. It also comes with the correct and useful Maven preinstalled. As well as Spring framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you had a local fail judging by this error. Try restart Eclipse and install this plugin again. But in general, to avoid such troubles, I would recommend you to install any Eclipse plugins manually from an [archive file](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/install-from-zip).

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tried many times with restarting eclipse also with different network (as may be chance of firewall). Installing manually will be the last option.

Comment: This's the easiest and most reliable way.